# C Code Compiles with No Errors but Doesn't Run Right (command line arguments and pointers)

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strcompare (char*);
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int argIndex;
for(argIndex = 1; argIndex <= argc; argIndex++)
{
    strcompare(argv[argIndex]);
    printf("%s has %d letters in it\n", argv[argIndex], strcompare(argv[argIndex]));
}
return 0;
}

int strcompare (char *str)
{
    int index, letterDex = 0;
    for (index = 0; *str != '0'; index++)
    {
        letterDex++;
    }
}
```

The assignment is to count the number of letters in a word, when I compile I don't get any errors, but when I try to run it it just doesn't work at all

```
./cma_length noah bruh conner
```

and nothing comes after it when I hit enter.

Comment: You should be getting at least one warning from your compiler. If youa re not turn all the warnings on.

Comment: What does `strcompare` *return* ? More to the point, does `strcompare` return *anything* ? And yet does it claim it will ? Also, check that `for` condition. Do you understand that will run until a hard *digit* character `'0'` is encountered, unbounded by anything else, and as you've provided  no such strings containing a `'0'` digit character in your input, your code will run pass their end-of-string terminators and off of the cliff of *undefined behavior*. Are you *sure* you didn't mean for that to stop on a terminator rather than a digit-`'0'` ?

Comment: Your code does not compile without errors with `gcc -Wall`. I'm getting `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like code which compiles. The function strcompare should return an int and in the implementation above it doesn't return anything. I assume there's a return letterDex; at the end of your function but you lost it when copying the code here.

In the for loop in the strcompare function you're comparing the *str to '0'. Now there are two things that are wrong here I think:

1. You're comparing *str to '0' but you don't change the pointer value. So you're comparing the first character to '0' all the time. You should either do str[index] != '0' or instead of using index increment the pointer.
2. I think that you want to look for a '\0' instead of '0'. The '\0' is a null terminator character meaning the end of the string.

The reason why you're not seeing anything happening is because you're stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: missing the problem that cause segmentation fault inside the forloop in the main function

Answer (score 6):

Four problems:

- missing the return statement on your `strcompare`
- youwasn't updating the pointer of the `char*`
- in C array that have 4 element, has the last element in index 3, so in the for loop condition, you have to check for`<`, not for `<=`
- `*str != '0'` is wrong, you are checking if the char is the char `0`, not the escape char, which is `\0` so check for this char in this way `*str != '\0'`

With those things done, the code will be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int strcompare (char*);
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int argIndex;
    for(argIndex = 1; argIndex < argc; argIndex++){
        strcompare(argv[argIndex]);
        printf("%s has %d letters in it\n", argv[argIndex], strcompare(argv[argIndex]));
    }
    return 0;
}

int strcompare (char *str){
     int letterDex;
     for (letterDex = 1; *str != '\0'; letterDex++){
         str++;
     }
     return letterDex;
}
```

Also the `index` variable was useless, so i've just removed it